# Why can't I access this method from another class?

Tags: java, android

I have the main class extends MapActivity, like this:

```
public class main extends MapActivity {
    private MapView mapView;

    ......//something

    public MapView getmapView() {
        return mapView;
    }

    ........//something
}
```

Why i couldn't access getmapView() method in another class,like this

```
MapView mv=main.getMapview()
```

Answer (score 1):

**You're confusing the syntax for accessing static methods with the syntax for accessing instance (i.e. non-static) methods.**

Do you want each instance of your `main` class to have it's own `MapView` object, or do you want all of your `main` objects to share a single `MapView`?

If you want each instance of your `main` class to have it's own instance of `MapView`, then you need to call the `getmapView()` method on an instance of the `main` class, rather than on the name of the class itself:

```
main myObject = new main();
MapView mv=myObject.getmapView();
```

If instead you want all of your `main` objects to share a single `MapView`, then your `getmapView()` method and the `mapView` member itself need to be declared as `static`...

```
public class main extends MapActivity {
  private static MapView mapView;

  ......//something

  public static MapView getmapView() {
     return mapView;
  }

  ......//something
}
```

...then you can call the static `getmapView()` method using the line of code you already posted:

```
MapView mv=main.getMapview();
```

Further reading: take a look at [this article](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) in the Java tutorials for further explanation.

Comment: Then you should **accept** it, RayZy. Notice also both of you are being inconsistent with capitalisation, and java is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

fisrt thing , if you want to access to your method using the name of your main class , your method should be a **static method** , and then you can do something like this :

```
MapView mv=main.getMapview();
```

and if you want to use it without static method, you should pass an instance of your main class to the other class .

if you want to use the static method then try this :

```
public class Main extends MapActivity {
    private static MapView mapView;

    ......//something

    public static MapView getmapView() {
        if(mapView == null)
               mapView = new MapView();
        return mapView;
    }
    ........//something
}
```

and in your second class you can simply use this :

```
MapView mv=Main.getMapview();
```

Comment: mapView will need to be static too then. You can't access instance data from within a static method.

Comment: yes i forgot the mensionne that on my code, therefore, it's the implementation of the design pattern : Singleton

Comment: Thanks, i got the points.  it need declared as static to allow outside calling.

Comment: you are welcome , we are here to help  .if it works for you , vote the question :)

Comment: No, RayZy, it hasn't got to do with outside calling. It's got to do with calling through the class (static) or calling through an instance (non-static).